# Pass an object to a method with Interface return type

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism

How do you pass an object to a method which has an Interface return type? Is this possible?

For eg:

```
public enum Objects{obj1, obj2, obj3 }

public class SomeClass1
{
    public string property1;
    public string property2;
    public string property3;    
}

public class SomeClass2
{
    private IList<IInterface> interface;
    public SomeClass2(IList<IInterface> interface)
    {
        this.interface = interface;
    }

    public Iinterface GetEnumObjects(SomeClass1 someClass1)
    {
        return interface.Where(o => o.isItTrue(someClass1)).FirstOrDefault();
    }    
}

public interface IInterface()
{
    Objects objects {get;}    
    public bool isItTrue(SomeClass1 someClass1);    
}

public static void main(string[] args)
{
    SomeClass1 someObject1 = new SomeClass 
    {
        property1 = "prop1"
        property1 = "prop2"
        property1 = "prop3"
    };

    // How can I pass an object to a method with interface return type?
    PassThisObject(someOtherObject );    
}
```

Comment: @Leo How should I Initialize SomeClass2() in Main to pass the object to GetEnumObjects() method?

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool isItTrue;
```

Should be.

```
public bool isItTrue(SomeClass1 someClass1)
```

Comment: Correct! Typed this thing in hurry

Comment: How should I Initialize SomeClass2() in Main to pass the object to GetEnumObjects method?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your example is not much clear. if the type's object you are passing implements that interface then sure you can. Example ...

```
//Method Definition
public Iinterface PassThisObject(Someclasssomeotherobject someOtherObject )
{
   //Your code here
}


//Class definition
class Someclasssomeotherobject : Iinterface
{
 //class members here
}

//You can call the method like

Someclasssomeotherobject someOtherObject = new Someclasssomeotherobject();

PassThisObject(someOtherObject );
```

**EDIT:**

Make changes to your code as below

```
//have your class implements the interface
public class SomeClass1 : IInterface
{
    public string property1;
    public string property2;
    public string property3;    
}


public static void main(string[] args)
{
    SomeClass1 someObject1 = new SomeClass 
    {
        property1 = "prop1"
        property1 = "prop2"
        property1 = "prop3"
    };
        //Create a list of IInterface
       List<IInterface> listofinterface  = new List<IInterface>();

       //Instanciate someclass2 passing the interface list created in earlier step
       SomeClass2 cls2 = new SomeClass2(listofinterface);

       //call your GetEnumObjects method passing the someclass1 object
       cls2.GetEnumObjects(someObject1);  
}
```

Comment: I get an error: 
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ConsoleApplication1.SomeClass2.GetEnumObjects(ConsoleApplication1.SomeClass1)'

Comment: How should I Initialize SomeClass2() in Main to pass the object to GetEnumObjects method?

Comment: @user793468, see edited answer. Make sure to clarify everything in your post and show only relevant code to avoid confusion and better your chances to get answer quickly and correctly.

Comment: I dont think we can create instance of any Interface

Comment: @user793468, Yep didn't see that. Should be fine now. Try again. `List` implements `IList`.